# How to delete rigid body cache?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, baking, cache

I can't delete rigid body cache from scene. When I delete old objects and add new ones they are acting like the old objects. I tried all options under rigid body cache panel in scene properties, Free bake, Bake All Dynamics and others but none of them is working. I wonder how can I delete old rigid body cache from scene?

[image]

Comment: Thats odd.. Free bake should do it. Is it possible you could upload the .blend?

Comment: Use [**blendExchange**](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload.

Comment: http://1drv.ms/1AMe3rG

Comment: @gandalf23   [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=70" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/70/)

Comment: Hello from 2020! It still doesn't work!

Answer (score 6):

Under the menu: *Scene selection* > *Rigid Body World* > *Rigid Body Cache* > *Free All Bakes* > *Reset Start and End* > **Bake**

This worked for me in 2.74. It took less than a minute to bake 325 frames.

Comment: This still does not work for me. Alt+A still produces old physics. So weird. But, 'Remove Rigid Body World' did

Comment: `Remove Rigid Body World` under *Rigid Body World* works great if you are trying to clean up a file as well. I think this is the right answer.

Comment: In what panel do I find the menu: Scene selection?

Answer (score 0):

Just click on the "x" on the right side of the rigid body options in the physics

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if cleaning cache doesn't work for you, I found it's easier to just change a few rigidbody properties, like mass or constraints threshold or whatever, that will let the rigidbody world recalculate the physics, at least for v3.4.